# Google Forms create new folder and doc. plance new doc in new folder

Tags: forms, file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

hey everyone hoping some out out there could give me a hand.
I currently have a Google form that fills my spreadsheet and then auto creates a doc based on that.
I am Very new at this so i cant seem to figure out the next part.
What im hopeing to have done is: once the form has been submitted that it auto creates a new sub folder in a folder and then the doc that is being created goes into that new folder.
The name of the folder needs to be the same as the Doc that was created.
here is what i have so far.
If any one could help with the codeing that would fix my issue i would be forever greatfull.

```
function onOpen() {
 const Ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = Ui.createMenu('autofillDocs');
menu.addItem('Create new Docs','createnewgoogledoc');
 menu.addToUi();
}

function createnewgoogledoc(){
  const googleDocsTemplate = 
DriveApp.getFileById('1zAmqED4EFdwVADHq3xGvEzTzvscTtIMpZOMkzV9Csa8');
 const destiationfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0AMUCDqCl3x3aUk9PVA');
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
 const Rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 Rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
   if (index === 0) return;
  if (row[14]) return;
   if (!row[1]) return;

   const copy = googleDocsTemplate.makeCopy(row[1] + " " +row[4] + " " + 
row[5],destiationfolder);
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
const body = doc.getBody();
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[0]).toLocaleDateString();

 body.replaceText('{{Options}}', row[3]);
body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', friendlyDate);
body.replaceText('{{Tag #}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Item}}', row[6]);
body.replaceText('{{Item 2}}', row[7]);
body.replaceText('{{Tag 2}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Item 3}}', row[8]);
body.replaceText('{{Tag 3}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Item 4}}', row[9]);
body.replaceText('{{Tag 4}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Item 5}}', row[10]);
body.replaceText('{{Tag 5}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{What is the issue}}', row[12]);
body.replaceText('{{SHOP}}', row[13]);

doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 15).setValue(url);
Logger.log(row)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a document and save it into a folder

What you do with it in the middle is  upto you

```
function createAndSave() {
  const dflr = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid)
  const t = DocumentApp.openById("template id");
  const d = DocumentApp.create("Nam1");//create new doc and rename
  //do your stuff in here
  const f = d.saveAndClose();
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": dflr.getId()}]}, d.getId());
}
```

You will need to enable the Drive API version 2 to run the last line